# UserTransaction in servlets

Tags: jpa, servlets, jta

I wonder if it is ok to use UserTransaction like in this scenario below.

EntityManager is not thread-safe so there is helper class.

```
public class EMProducer {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager createEM() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

and the Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            MyEntity entity = new MyEntity("test entity");
            //try...
            utx.begin();
            em.persist(entity);
            utx.commit();
            //catch...
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is always the same instance of UserTransaction object injected. Is it ok or it should be done differently? Is the UserTransaction thread-safe?
When I use BMT EJBs there is also always the same UserTransaction instance injected so I think it is, but I would like to be sure how this works.

(I know about EJBs, @Transactional, that I shouldn't add business logic to servlets etc. but I'm asking about this use case)